Configure the protocol:port under target group to HTTP:100, security group for ec2 instance allows all, why it doesn't work?
In AWS, when setting up the ALB, and under target group, based on this post protocol:port is used by the ALB to route traffic to targeted instance in target group? is this correct?

I notice that my instance is unhealthy, is there easy way to see what's causing this?
I played around with this, I configure that to be HTTP:100, then in the targeted instance I only have one instance, with security group as follows

Why this is not working, deaspite the inbound rule is set to allow all protocol for all ports?

The health check settings can have different protocol/port configuration. Please edit your question to show the Target Group health check settings. Also, do you actually have an HTTP service running on the EC2 instance, listening on port 100?

Hey! I think that's the problem I was googling around and realized I'm running the default systemctl start httpd which is by default 80 right? so I am figuring out a way to make it to 100 now, this is likely the the issue

Yeah, as per comment, this is what I did in the "User details" under advanced setting when launching instance
#!/bin/bash
yum update -y
yum install -y httpd
systemctl start httpd
systemctl enable httpd

I bootstrap the http server using the default port 80
Then to change the port, I use EC2 Instance connect, then edit this file
sudo vi /etc/httpd/conf edit httpd.conf
add Listen 100 under Listen 80
then sudo sytemctl restart httpd.service
Then I check accessing EC2 instance IP using port 100
http://18.191.66.176:100/
Then I test using the ALB DNS, all work fine!
